# Override method in extended Class with same erasure

Tags: java, erasure

So I have some classes like `BooleanLogger`, `IntLogger` etc., which implement my own `Logger` interface.

This is the `Logger` interface:

```java
public interface Logger {
    String serialise();
    Object deserialise(String value);
    void setValue(Object value);
}
```

Here's a snippet of `BooleanLogger`:

```java
public class BooleanLogger extends MutableBoolean implements Logger {
    private MutableBoolean value;

    // ...

    @Override
    public String serialise() {
        return serialise(this.value.booleanValue());
    }

    public static String serialise(Boolean value) {
        return Boolean.toString(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialise(String value) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Boolean value) {
        this.value = new MutableBoolean(value);
        logChange();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = new MutableBoolean((Boolean) value);
        logChange();
    }

    private void logChange() {
        System.out.println(this.value); // temporary
    }
}
```

So the basic idea is essentially to override any setter methods within `MutableBoolean` such that we log the new value whenever it's modified. I've implemented that part trivially so far, but that's not what I'm concerned about.

Elsewhere in my code, I have a map `Map<String, Logger> loggerMap`. I want to be able to get a `Logger` from this map and set its value, given a serialised `String value`. For example:

```java
Logger logger = loggerMap.get("myLogger1");
logger.setValue(logger.deserialise(value));
```

It's done this way because I don't know the type of `Logger` I'm getting, so everything needs to work regardless.

Note the reason for this serialising/deserialising is these values are coming from Redis and hence are stored as Strings.

The problem I'm having is that in the individual loggers like `BooleanLogger`, it says:

> 'setValue(T)' in 'org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.Mutable' clashes
> with 'setValue(Object)' in 'myLogger.BooleanLogger'; both methods have
> same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

The only solution I can think of is to no longer extend from `MutableBoolean`, `MutableInt` etc., and instead just copy all the methods into my own `BooleanLogger`, `IntLogger` classes. However, I have these classes for a fair few types and it would quickly become cumbersome and frustrating to do it this way. Right now I only have to deal with any methods that change the underlying value.

As far as the logic goes, I've already successfully implemented everything with my `public class ArrayLogger<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements Logger {}` as this is the only one that does not extend from a Mutable type that clashes on the `setValue` method.

**EDIT:** I've realised that even if I make my own class, I'll have the same issue just

> 'setValue(Object)' in 'myLogger.BooleanLogger' clashes with
> 'setValue(T)' in 'org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.Mutable'; both
> methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Assuming `public class BooleanLogger implements Mutable<Boolean>, Serializable, Comparable<MutableBoolean>, Logger {}`

So unless I make my own `Mutable<T>` type (and possibly others...), I may need a different solution.

Comment: Can't you make `Logger` generic and extend `Mutable`?

Comment: @shmosel could you elaborate?

Comment: `public interface Logger<T> extends Mutable<T> { String serialise(); Object deserialise(String value); }` `public class BooleanLogger extends MutableBoolean implements Logger<Boolean> {}`

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is that your code doesn't actually make sense.

This part, specifically:

```
interface  Logger {
  void setValue(Object value);
}
```

You've broken the type system here. That says to me I can call `setValue(whateverObjectIPlease)` on any logger of any stripe and it should just work. Turns out that is incorrect - if I invoke `.setValue(x)` on any Logger whose actual type is `BooleanLogger`, and `x` is anything but a `Boolean` instance, it fails.

Hence, this is not great API. Now also consider that it fundamentally clashes with apache's Mutable hierarchy and it gets worse.

There's a second fundamental problem in your design.

Your BooleanLogger class is confused about itself and is its own factory.

Specifically, the `deserialize` method has **nothing to do with a BooleanLogger instance**. It doesn't interact with any field whatsoever, and could have been `static`, other than the fact that you want it to participate in class hierarchies and static methods don't.

**That is what factories are for**. They let you abstract non-instance parts of class structures (so, constructors, and static methods).

One way to go is to make a `LoggerFactory` or `LoggerType` interface, have exactly 1 instance for each type. You'd have something like:

```
interface LoggerFactory<T extends Logger> {
  T deserialize(String in);
}

class BooleanLoggerFactory<BooleanLogger> {
  BooleanLogger deserialize(String in) {
    return new BooleanLogger(Boolean.parseBoolean(value));
  }
}
```

Voila - you can abstract that way to your hearts content.

But, if you find that too complicated, just 'collapse' your setValue and deserialize methods.

Right now your `deserialize` method is lying in the sense that it says it is an instance method but it really isn't.. and your `setValue` method is lying in the sense that it indicates any object of any stripe will do when that isn't the case either.

But... **combine the two... and both lies disappear in a puff of smoke**. Behold:

```
interface Logger {
  /** Sets the value of this logger by deserializing {@code in}. */
  abstract void deserialize(String in);

  // completely delete setValue. It has no business being here.
}

class BooleanLogger implements Logger {
  @Override public void deserialize(String in) {
    setValue(Boolean.parseBoolean(in));
  }

  public void setValue(boolean b) {
    this.v = v;
  }
}
```

Problem solved. If you really insist on having that `setValue` method be part of `Logger` itself, introduce generics. It was your choice to sign up to apache's Mutable type hierarchy, and it uses generics, so - you signed up for that too:

```
public interface Logger<T> {
    String serialise();
    Object deserialise(String value);
    void setValue(T value);
}

public class BooleanLogger implements Logger<Boolean> {
  ...

  @Override public void setValue(Boolean b) {
    this.v = b.booleanValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I see what you mean about `setValue`, however it only works because it's part of the interface. The idea is I need to be able to run `setValue` on a `Logger` I've taken out of the `loggerMap` without knowing its type.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about factories to understand or implement the first example, but I imagine it has the same issues.

Comment: For the third example, it fails for a similar reason as my current code. As soon as I try and do something like `logger.setValue(logger.deserialise(value));`, it says "Required type: capture of ?. Provided: capture of ?. Change 1st parameter of abstract method 'setValue' from 'T' to 'Object'"

Comment: And then accepting this change in IntelliJ gets me back to where I began ^

Comment: `deserialise` is `void` -- it calls `setValue` itself.

Comment: @tgdavies Ah yes I see that now, but I would like to `deserialise` without setting as well. And I'm sure it will just tell me the same thing for `deserialise` as it did for `setValue`

Comment: The factory example _does not_ have the same issues.

Comment: As I explained, 'deserialize without setting' doesn't make sense here in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps instead of dejectedly assuming nothing will work, you may want to try some of stuff. I wrote it down because, you know. That's what you should be doing. Not for kicks and giggles.

Comment: Does `deserialiseAndSet()` not violate the single responsibility principle?

Comment: @JP such esoteric style maxims should _always_ be inferior to practicality, of course.

Comment: @JP It also kinda shows what the problem is with rote adherence to some guidelines you read in a style book: The notion that you have an __instance__ method that does a job that has nothing at all to do with that specific instance is an order of magnitude worse, but I bet that style books of yours doesn't have a page that mentions it :)